# iOs9 xcode 7 : no code signing identities

Tags: ios, iphone, swift2, ios9, xcode7

Hi guys now that xcode7 became some things have been changing that I've never saw before in xcode 6. Now that I fixed every changes it tells me: "no code signing identities found no valid signing identities (i.e. certificate and private key pair)"

I've been looking for some help like restarting the xcode but it didn't solve the problem..any help? I'll appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably Xcode lost connection with your developers account. To fix that simply go to Project Settings -> General and click on "Fix Issue":

[image: Like shown on this screen]

And click "Add" to set up Xcode with existing account or click "Join a program" to buy a license if you don't have one :)